# Há alguma maneira de eu acessar um pdf através do código fonte?

Tags: pdf

A minha dúvida é simples: há alguma maneira de eu baixar um arquivo pdf à partir do código fonte da página? A seguir, há um exemplo real extraído de um site e gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito de acessar o pdf (1d026fee0f3144034bd87b6318fd083f.pdf) através das informações fornecidas.

```
            JsonArquivo  = {"id_arquivo":"1843","codigo":"F54Q21","data":"2020-10-28 09:30:00","prazoDownload":"2020-10-28 11:00:00","prazoEnvio":"2020-10-31 11:10:00","prazoEnvio":"2020-10-31 11:00:00","file":"1d026fee0f3144034bd87b6318fd083f.pdf"} 
            </script><button 
            class="btn btn-success downloadFile"
            style="display:none"
            data-dados='{"id_arquivo":"1843","codigo":"F54Q21","data":"2020-10-28 09:30:00","prazoDownload":"2020-10-31 11:00:00","prazoEnvio":"2020-10-31 11:10:00","prazoEnvio":"2020-10-31 11:00:00","file":"1d026fee0f3144034bd87b6318fd083f.pdf"}'
            data-id_arquivo=""1843""
            id="downloadFile-1843"
```

Desde já agradeço por qualquer resposta.

Comment: Sua pergunta está vaga quanto aos recursos ou linguagem que deseja extrair/tem disponíveis para você, mas assumindo que seja tanto faz, tem uma solução funcional e disponível no github, dê uma olhada https://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/

Comment: Mais uma com Javascript, também está disponível aqui https://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001948

Comment: Depois disso sugiro que dê uma leitura no link para te auxiliar em como formular uma boa pergunta e conseguir a ajuda de que precisa da comunidade. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask